# Why isn't my new microphone working?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone

I just got an Antlion Modmic microphone, along with a Rockit headphone/mic to TRRS splitter. I've got everything set up, but my late 2011 mbp 15" just won't recognize the microphone as an input. I should have under my audio inputs box in system preferences a thing saying "external microphone," but I don't. I also don't think this is a hardware problem, either, it works fine on an iPhone.

Things I have tried:

-Plug the microphone in the Audio in Jack
----is not a powered mic input that my mic needs

-Tried plugging it in to the splitter first then in to the computer- still nothing

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Where do you plug it in ?

Comment: I plug the headphone and microphone into the Rockit adapter, which I then plug into the headphone jack on my computer.

Comment: Did you try plugging the mic in to the jack next to it ?

Comment: Your model has 2 jacks, one is audio out, the other is audio in.

Comment: I know, I tried that, but that mic jack is not a powered mic input that my mic needs.

Comment: Then, try plugging it in to the splitter first then in to the computer. I am still wondering if you have the right splitter? did you research that?

Comment: I have done that, and it is the right splitter. It's actually the splitter recommended by the manufacturer!

Comment: All the things you have already done but not telling us about the lead to pointless discussions.

Comment: having this issue right now

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.modmic.com/pages/faq:

> For Macs you'll need a power source like an iMic to use the line-in, or an adapter like this to use the headset jack, or and adapter like this to use a USB port.

Unfortunately, I do not have the reputation to link what was referenced in the FAQ, you'll have to visit the FAQ yourself.

Comment: You see where it says "an adapter like this to use the headset jack"? That's the adapter I have.